keyboard scanner using android phone camera
how to make a program where you scan the a keyboard using android phone camera and it will tell if its US, France, German, Spanish, Arabic and other types of keyboards but it wont detect any if there are wrong keys
I am new making projects

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
